# Redirect from simple product to parent product

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-association

> I want to display all the associated simple products on the category-
>   pages and link them to the their parent product.

How this can be achieved?

One simple product is associated with only one parent.

Answer (score 3):

Here I use configurable product as an example. You can pluginize Product View controller.

Try following way:

**SR/StackExchange/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
        <plugin name="sr_product_controller_view" type="SR\StackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**If you redirect to Parent Product use following code:**

**SR/StackExchange/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Product/View.php**

```
namespace SR\StackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product;

class View
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http
     */
    protected $http;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product
     */
    protected $productHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable
     */
    protected $configurable;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $http
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $http,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable
    ) {
        $this->http = $http;
        $this->productHelper =$productHelper;
        $this->configurable = $configurable;
    }

    /**
     * Product view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $productId = (int) $subject->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $parentIds = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
        $parentId = array_shift($parentIds);

        if($parentId) {
            $categoryId = (int)$subject->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
            $productId = (int)$parentId;

            $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);

            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $product */
            $product = $this->productHelper->initProduct($productId, $subject, $params);;
            $this->http->setRedirect($product->getProductUrl(), 301);
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

[Update]

**Instead of redirecting, can I just show the parent product url.**

**SR/StackExchange/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Product/View.php**

```
namespace SR\StackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product;

class View
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable
     */
    protected $configurable;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable
    ) {
        $this->configurable = $configurable;
    }

    /**
     * Product view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $productId = (int) $subject->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $parentIds = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
        $parentId = array_shift($parentIds);

        if($parentId) {
            $subject->getRequest()->setParam('id', $parentId);
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Overwrite following template

Magento_Swatches::product/view/renderer.phtml
Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Add following code

```
<script>
    history.pushState({}, '', '<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getProductUrl();?>');
</script>
```

Comment: The code is showing parent product page but url is of the child product, I want the redirect i.e url should be of parent product only.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Instead of redirecting, can I just show the parent product url on the child product on product list page.

Comment: @AnshuMishra if you assign parent product url in product list page, then system will be slow. Check updated answer, may be it will help you.

Comment: Can you explain how to overwrite the templates and where to add the script in more detail?

Comment: @SohelRana the updated solution in your answer works well. Is there also a way to pre-select the configurable options, depending on the simple product that was selected?

Comment: @primo Have you got solution for  pre-select the configurable options. I have same issue ? Please share your solution.

Comment: @SohelRana Is there any way to pre-select the configurable options when open simple product from search page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getProductUrl()` in order to link simple products with configurable parent product. For this, the new URL of simple products should look like for example:

> **`/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html#143=167&93=53`**

where

`/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html` - configurable product URL,

`143`, `93` - attributes IDs,

`167`, `53` - option IDs.

---

I made `VCT Simple Product URL` module on Magento Marketplace that solves this problem.